TS interface doesn't recognize fx properties when they're set within the function itself
I'm trying to to use ts to declare a factory function that also has a property on the function itself (meant to simulate a static property of sorts). I use an interface to do this.
interface MyFunc {
    (): object
    staticData: object
}

The problem is that I'm setting the property of the function within the function itself like so:
const Func1: MyFunc = () => {
    Func1.staticData = {data1: 1, data2: 2}
    return {
        staticData: Func1.staticData
    }
}

But ts gives the error: Property 'staticData' is missing in type '() => { staticData: object; }' but required in type 'MyFunc'.
I can fix this by adding the staticData after the function is declared, but then the return object from the function no longer gets access to it.
const Func1: MyFunc = () => {
    return {
        staticData: {data1: 1, data2: 2} //loses ability to refer to static value now
    }
}
Func1.staticData = {data1: 1, data2: 2} //fixes warning

Is there a way to fix the interface for this function so that I can keep my first way of doing it and not have ts throw an error.

I think I understand the problem. In my first way of doing this, Func1.staticData doesn't actually exist unless the function gets called at leat once. So perhaps that's why ts was giving the error. I think the best I can do is just make this property optional in the interface. Not the end of the world.

Your understanding is absolutely correct. But whats wrong with using this: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgLIE8BiBXEDnIDeAsAFAEEAUAlAFzID2ARgFYQJhkXIDOYcYYAgAiAuPWZsOZAL5kyCBiD7IceAIz0Ma-AF5kNZLoB8RLhSgQw2KCDPluFPgKEBlMFFABzejvUA6Z0ERMXMCOVIIv0D+YNF+IyIAEzFNZHUAGmQU-gAmelyZZAB6YqA ?

I agree with @TusharShahi, why not just move Func1.staticData = {data1: 1, data2: 2} outside the function? That is, why do you think "then the return object from the function no longer gets access to it"? That's not accurate.

@Tushar-Shahi You're right; that works fine. I got messed up thinking the return object wouldn't have access to properties set later in the code, but it actually would in this case. I'm closing this question as malformed.

I’m voting to close this question because the question was incorrect and made wrong assumptions.
